# For some reason, I need to use Firefox 46. What is the version of geckodriver to use for Selenium 2.53 and Firefox 46?

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm using Selenium 2.53 and Firefox 46, which version of Geckodriver should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use geckodriver with those versions. It should work as is. `2.53` defaulted to using the legacy firefox webdriver (not geckodriver) and that is what will work best with `FF46`

Comment: Really thanks for your answer, it clarify more on my understanding. But may I know where we can get the legacy firefox webdriver?

Comment: The legacy firefox driver is built into selenium, you don't need to get it from anywhere

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot indeed.